# overload array operator for mystring class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c-strings

I need help figuring out how to overload the array operator for a `MyString` class that I have to create. I already have everything else figured out, but the arrays are giving me trouble, for some reason.

Here is my header file:

```cpp
#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>  // For string library functions
#include <cstdlib>  // For exit() function
using namespace std;

// MyString class: An abstract data type for handling strings
class MyString
{
private:
    char *str;
    int len;
public:
    // Default constructor.
    MyString()
    { 
        str = 0; 
        len = 0;
    }
     
    // Convert and copy constructors. 
    MyString(char *);
    MyString(MyString &);
    
    // Destructor. 
    ~MyString()
    { 
        if (len != 0)
            delete [] str;
        str = 0;
        len = 0;
    }
     
    // Various member functions and operators.   
    int length() { return len; }
    char *getValue() { return str; };
    MyString operator+=(MyString &);
    MyString operator+=(const char *);
    MyString operator=(MyString &);
    MyString operator=(const char *);
    bool operator==(MyString &);
    bool operator==(const char *);
    bool operator!=(MyString &);
    bool operator!=(const char *);
    bool operator>(MyString &);
    bool operator>(const char *);
    bool operator<(MyString &);
    bool operator<(const char *);
    bool operator>=(MyString &);
    bool operator>=(const char*);
    bool operator<=(MyString &);
    bool operator<=(const char *);
    MyString operator [](MyString *);
    
    // Overload insertion and extraction operators.
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, MyString &);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &, MyString &);
};
#endif
```

What would the body look like for `MyString::operator []`?

```cpp
MyString MyString::operator [](MyString *)
{
    ... what goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  MyString MyString::operator [](MyString *)
> ```

That's not how you should typically use a subscript operator.

What do you expect when you are using the `[]` operator? By the way you declared it, you are using a string pointer as argument, and receiving a string as return.

Usually, you pass an index type (commonly an unsigned-integer like `size_t`) and return the *character* at that position. If that's what you want, you should do something along these lines:

```
 char& MyString::operator [](size_t position)
 {
     // some error handling
     return str[position];
 }
 
 char MyString::operator [](size_t position) const { /* ... */ }
```

For overall guidelines on overloading operators, take a look at [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/).

Also, I would point out that your destructor is a bit odd:

```
if (len != 0)
    delete [] str;
    str = 0;
    len = 0;
```

Your indentation level suggests that you expect everything to happen inside the `if` statement, but only the first one will. That is not particularly dangerous in this case, because only the `delete` would suffice.

There is no problem in `delete`ing a null pointer, and `str` and `len` will be destroyed shortly after, so you don't have to bother resetting them.

Comment: Yep, I forgot my curly braces for the if statement. Thanks for the help

Comment: Operator overloading should always be coherent with the semantics for arrays. For array operator, you should return a reference or a const reference. Therefore, I suggest you go for @R Sahu answer

Comment: True. The answer focused on the overall logic. That's why I linked a much more complete answer about overloading guidelines, but it's likely that people will just copy and paste... added that the rest for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for using the array operator with an object of the given class is:

```
MyString s("Test");
char c = s[0];
```

The argument to the function is an integral value.

Hence, the operator needs to be declared as:

```
// The non-const version allows you to change the 
// content using the array operator.
char& operator [](size_t index);

// The nconst version allows you to just get the 
// content using the array operator.
char operator [](size_t index) const;
```

Comment: Why should the non const version be returned as char& instead of just char?

Comment: @imalogginin, then you can use `s[0] = 'a';` to set the value. If the function returns a `char`, you can't do that.